# "Готовить сырники (-) достаточно просто..."

Tags: пунктуация

"Готовить сырники - достаточно просто..." Нужно ли здесь тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире здесь не является обязательным, но возможно как авторский знак. Для передачи интонационной паузы, например, эффекта неожиданности, противопоставления и т. п. Насколько все это актуально для конкретного текста, надо смотреть по контексту.

*Хотя, надо признать, очень часто тире в подобных случаях совершенно ошибочно ставят по аналогии с §165 "Правил-56". ("Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если подлежащее выражено формой именительного падежа существительного, а сказуемое неопределенной формой или если оба они выражены неопределенной формой") - здесь это не применимо, поскольку требуемые условия не выполняются*